# extracting exponent from polynomial c++ using c string

Tags: c++, c-strings

I'm trying to extract the value of the coeffecients and the exponent from a polynomial. I have already succeeded in extracting the coeffients using `strtok`. I applied the same concept to find the exponent, but I don't know how to use `strtok` to extract the string AFTER the delimiters or skip the first character, and `strtok` is the only extracting tool I know.

This is the main function

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void extractCoeff (char *str, char *copy);
void extractExp (char *str, char *copy);
int main()
{
    const int SIZE = 150; // size for string input

    char *string;
    string = new char[SIZE];
    cout << "Enter the polynomial\n"<<"minus sign must not have a blank with a coeff";
    cin.ignore();
    cin.getline(string, SIZE); // input string example: -4x^0 + x^1 + 4x^3 -3x^4

    char *copy1;
    copy1 = new char[SIZE];
    strcpy(copy1, string);  
    extractCoeff(string, copy1);

    cout << endl << endl;
    char *copy2;
    copy2 = new char[SIZE];
    strcpy(copy2, string); 
    extractExp(string, copy2);


    return 0;
}
```

This is the function to extract coeff (worked)

```
void extractCoeff (char *str, char *copy)
{   
    char *p = strtok(str, " +"); // extract the first time
    char *search;
    int counter = 0;
    while (p) 
    {
        search = strstr(p, "x^");
        cout << "Token: " << p << endl;
        cout << "Search " << search << endl;
        p = strtok(NULL, " +");
        counter++;
    }

    cout << copy << endl;

    // find coeff
    int *coefficient;
    coefficient = new int[counter];

    p = strtok(copy, " +"); // extract the second time to find coeff
    int a = 0;
    while (p)
    {
        cout << "p: " << p << endl;
        long coeff;
        if (*p == 'x')
        {
           coeff = 1;
        }
        else if (*p == NULL)
        {
            coeff = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            char *endptr;
            coeff = strtol(p, &endptr, 10);
        }
        coefficient[a] = coeff;
        p = strtok(NULL, " +");
        a++;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
        cout << coefficient[i] << endl;
}
```

This is the function to extract exponents (not working)

```
void extractCoeff (char *str, char *copy)
{   
    char *p = strtok(str, " +"); // extract the first time
    char *search;
    int counter = 0;
    while (p) 
    {
        search = strstr(p, "x^");
        cout << "Token: " << p << endl;
        cout << "Search " << search << endl;
        p = strtok(NULL, " +");
        counter++;
    }

    cout << copy << endl;

    // find coeff
    int *coefficient;
    coefficient = new int[counter];

    p = strtok(copy, " +"); // extract the second time to find coeff
    int a = 0;
    while (p)
    {
        cout << "p: " << p << endl;
        long coeff;
        if (*p == 'x')
        {
           coeff = 1;
        }
        else if (*p == NULL)
        {
            coeff = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            char *endptr;
            coeff = strtol(p, &endptr, 10);
        }
        coefficient[a] = coeff;
        p = strtok(NULL, " +");
        a++;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
        cout << coefficient[i] << endl;
}

void extractExp (char *str, char *copy)
{   
    char *p = strtok(str, " x^"); // extract the first time
    //char *search;
    int counter = 0;
    while (p) 
    {
        //search = strstr(p, "x^");
        //cout << "Token: " << p << endl;
        //cout << "Search " << search << endl;
        p = strtok(NULL, " x^");
        counter++;
    }

    cout << copy << endl;

    // find coeff
    int *exp;
    exp = new int[counter];

    p = strtok(copy, " x^"); // extract the third time
    int b = 0;
    while (p)
    {
        cout << "p2: " << p << endl;
        int expVal;
        if (*p == NULL)
        {
            expVal = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            char *endptr;
            expVal = strtol(p, &endptr, 10);
        }
        exp[b] = expVal;
        p = strtok(NULL, " x^");
        b++;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
        cout << exp[i] << endl;
}
```

Comment: You should tell us how it "does not work". What do you expect to see, what do you get?

Comment: Maybe a better idea is to parse the complete input using a regular expression. You could use e.g. [`boost::regex`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html), or `std::regex` from the new C++11 standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that `strtok` is destructive. You partly seem to know that, as you make a copy to be able to use it twice in the functions. But after `extractCoeff` returns to main, the content of the C-string pointed to by `string` is damaged, so when you call `extractExp` you pass two copies of a badly truncated string.

In C++ you should use `std::string` for handling strings. With `std::string` you can use the member functions `find`, `find_first_of` and `find_first_not_of` to locate the substrings, you are looking for and use `substr` to extract them *without* destroying the original string.

You can do similar things on C strings, using C functions, but that would be a C question. (Using `cout` and C++ headers makes your program not valid as a C program, but everything else is pure C rather than idiomatic C++.)

And, by the way: `strtok` is not something you should learn as the way to parse strings. It is destructive, it can't be used reentrantly and on some platform is not thread-safe. Unless you have very good reasons to need destructive in-place parsing over alternatives, don't use it or its slightly better kin (in POSIX) `strtok_r`.

Comment: @Lam Nguyen decide: C or C++.

Comment: @qPCR4vir regex is probably the better tool to get the job done in production code. But not to learn working with character sequences.

Comment: Good point. @Lam Nguyen : Are you learning string/char array manipulation or just want to parse your polynom?

Comment: By the way @JoergB, I agree with you +1.

Comment: thanks for pointing that out, however let's just focus on how can I use strtok to extract the exponents in this problem, let's just remove all the parts of getting the coefficients