# overload * operator to multiply 2 polynomials

Tags: c++, polynomial-math

I'm trying to write multiply 2 polynomials using overloading * operator

This is the overloading * func

```
Polynomial Polynomial::operator * (const Polynomial &right)
{
    Polynomial temp;
    temp.setPolynomial(right.maxExp + maxExp + 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < maxExp; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < right.maxExp; j++)
            temp.poly[1][i+j] += poly[0][i] * right.poly[0][j];
    }
    return temp;
}
```

The array result, where 1st row is the coefficients and the second row stores the exponents.

```
The first (original) polynomial is: (degree = 4, F = x^2)
0 0 1 0 0
0 0 2 0 0
The second polynomial is: (degree = 4, F = x^2)
0 0 1 0 0
0 0 2 0 0
The result polynomial is: // the location of the result is right (x^4)
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Polynomial class

```
class Polynomial
{
private:
    int **poly;
    int maxExp;
    void createPolynomialArray(int);
public:
    Polynomial();
    Polynomial(int); // constructor
    Polynomial(const Polynomial &); // copy constructor
    ~Polynomial(); // destructor

    // setter
    void setCoefficient(int,int);
    void setPolynomial(int);

    // getters
    int getTerm() const; // get the maxExp (highest exponent)
    int getCoefficient(int,int) const; // get a specific exponential value

    // overloading operators
    void operator=(const Polynomial &); // assignment
    Polynomial operator+(const Polynomial &); // addition
    Polynomial operator-(const Polynomial &); // substraction
    Polynomial operator*(const Polynomial &);
}
```

Question: what's wrong with my code that it produces that values? Thanks!

Comment: Can you please show polynomial equivalent of one of the inputs

Comment: @Toms yeah I wrote it next to the output F1 = F2 = x^2

Comment: @Herious As I can the present output..I think there is no problem. So I removed my comment

Comment: Have you considered that you can use a 1d array by realizing that the exponent is implicitly related to the subscript of the coefficient. `maxExp - forCounterVariable`.

Comment: Is there any part of this task that is *not* being cranked on SO? I only ask because of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15182448/overload-operator-to-add-2-polynomials-c), and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15173617/overload-the-operator-to-add-2-polynomials), and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15156565/extracting-exponent-from-polynomial-c-using-c-string), and then [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15166585/spilt-a-string-of-polynomial-to-get-the-degree-values). Perhaps a little more thought into the problem space?

Comment: Offhand, are you allowed to use `std::list<>` in this assignment? I think it would do *wonders* for your end-goal, or even better, a map.

Comment: @WhozCraig, my apology, you know I tried to write but I'm stuck. Well the hardest parts are solved now, no more polynomials; and no, I don't know how to use list :)

Comment: @Herious the map would be the real cats-pajamas for what it looks like you're trying to do. A list would be a bit more work, but still doable. Think of a map that uses the exponent (degree) of a polynomial term as the "key", and the "value" is the coefficient. I was just curious if there were limitations established on which parts of the standard library you could use vs. not use. No biggie. Glad you got it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this you are updating the result exponent with multiple of coefficients;

```
 temp.poly[1][i+j] += poly[0][i] * right.poly[0][j];
```

I think the code should be

```
for (int j = 0; j < right.maxExp; j++)
{
    temp.poly[0][i+j] += poly[0][i] * right.poly[0][j];
    if (temp.poly[0][i+j] != 0)
        temp.poly[1][i+j] = i+j;
}
```

Also i think in your code storing exponents is redundant information as position in array itself reflects the exponent

Comment: thanks, the intended [i][j] store correct value but somehow it store other values too `The first (original) polynomial is:
0 0 1 0 0
0 0 2 0 0
The second polynomial is:
0 0 1 0 0
0 0 2 0 0
The result polynomial is:
0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 0 0 0`

Comment: :-).. If you dont want exponents for variables with zero coefficents then check my modification. Add a condition for checking zero

Comment: @Herious, you really should consider that you don't need to store the exponents...